# Can I use cocoa bindings and delegation at the same time in a tableview?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I use cocoa bindings for my table's datasource. My question is if I can use and the nstableviedelegate methods for this table to customize each row style.

From what I see delegation doesn't work, methods are not called but I am not sure if I am right.

If so, is there a way to use both in conjunction?

Comment: You can use the table view's delegate as well as bindings. If your delegate methods aren't working it's because you've failed to set the delegate appropriately - bindings are irrelevant here.

Comment: @PaulPatterson thank you I'll double check my setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What Are Cocoa Bindings?
> In the simplest functional sense, the Cocoa bindings technology provides a means of keeping model and view values synchronized without you having to write a lot of “glue code.” It allows you to establish a mediated connection between a view and a **piece of data**, “binding” them such that a change in one is reflected in the other.
>
> The NSTableViewDataSource protocol declares the methods that an instance of NSTableView uses to **provide the data** to a table view and allow editing of the contents of its data source object.
>
> NSTableViewDelegate:
> A set of optional methods you implement in a table view delegate to **customize the behavior** of the table view.

Use either a data source or bindings to provide the data. You can use cocoa bindings and delegation at the same time in a tableview. You can use bindings to provide the data and a data source to customize drag & drop.

Comment: Ok, I'll double check my delegation set up and I 'll report back!